# mysql gone when Magento getting hitted by 300 user at the same time

Tags: mysql, magento, caching

I got a magento error :
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

I suspect it was because of about 300 user hit my website at the same time.

My VPS spec:

Centos 6.5 64,
Linode 2gb Ram, 2 Core,
Apache 2.2,
Mysql 5.5,
Panel Webuzo,
no apc, no memcache, no anykind of cache

This is my.cnf setting

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
key_buffer_size=128M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Question:
What server type you recommend? And is it really helpful to install cache?
Sorry to ask, im a newbie in VPS things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install FPC this will reduce mysql load substantially.

So before upgrading server its recommended that you install FPC.

Also make sure for all listing flat tables are used.

if still there is load issue I recommend use of Solr and use some Solr bridge or make some modules to remove some load from mysql to Solr.

Comment: What FPC you recommend me? Im using opcache and memcache now. and its getting better

Comment: There are few reputed extension provider just check there review and use.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the issue can be solved without changing the server, as the amount of 300 users is too small and is unlikely to trigger such a problem.    We advise you to test server loads (with cache enabled) and optimize some settings, such as:

mysql (my.cnf), the existing settings change to:

```
[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 64M
thread_concurrency = 2
key_buffer = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

- install memcached, set saving sessions to memcached;
- install php-apc.

Please let us know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried it. But Using OpCache (default from php 5.5), and memcached. and use Nginx as reverse proxy (I have no idea what it is, my friend help me to install this). Mysql not down. However, loading speed is very slow. MAybe I should need to trim apache module. Thank you!!

Comment: Well, then try some extensions for caching. Hope it will help.